# How to assign Nth element of **ptr to a variable?

Tags: c++

I am new to C++, but hopefully I asked this question somewhat correctly.

If there is a **ptr, storing multiple pointers to C-style strings, how is it possible to assign the Nth element of the **ptr to a variable?

```
const char** audioArrays[]{ turretDetectionWavFiles, turretActivationWavFiles, turretSearchingWavFiles, turretPowerDownWavFiles, turretAttackWavFiles, turretMovedWavFiles,
                            turretDie };
```

0th element of **ptr is turretDetectionWavFiles[]

```
const char* turretDetectionWavFiles[]{ "turret_active_1.wav", "turret_active_2.wav", "turret_active_3.wav", "turret_active_4.wav", "turret_active_5.wav", 
                                          "turret_active_6.wav", "turret_active_7.wav", "turret_active_8.wav" };
```

Here, I always get "turret_activate_1.wav"

```
void AudioClass::playAudio(char* incomingData, int MAX_DATA_LENGTH, const char** audioArrays, 
                           const int sizeOfAudioArrays)
const char* audioArraysChars{}; 
int audioArraysIndex{};
int strcmpResult{};

if ((strcmpResult = strcmp(incomingData, "turretDetectionWavFiles") == 0)) //turretDetectionWavFiles
{
     audioArraysChars = audioArrays[0];
     audioArraysIndex = 0;
}
```

So instead of assigning "turret_active_1.wav", I'd need to assign one of the elements (e.g. the 3rd element) of NOT the turretDetectionWavFiles array (audioArrays[0]), but turretActivationWavFiles (audioArrays[1]) array.

Comment: your example doesn't compile. I guess it should be `audioArraysChars = audioArrays[1][2]` for the third element of `turretActivationWavFiles`

Comment: Yes, I did not include the whole function. Now its corrected!

Comment: You pass some array of `const char *` to this function and select the first element of it. It's not clear what problem you have. If you need to select some value from `turretActivationWavFiles` for example, you obviously need to pass this array somehow. But you should really consider to put all of this in semantically meaningfull classes.

Comment: @Alan Birtles: I get the following error if I try your way - a value of type "char" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "const char *"

Comment: Is `audioArrays` a `const char**[]` or `const char**`? Please provide a [mre]

Comment: audioArrays should be a const char**[], as per the following definition, but I am not sure about the difference between the two:                    
const char** audioArrays[]{ turretDetectionWavFiles, turretActivationWavFiles, turretSearchingWavFiles, turretPowerDownWavFiles, turretAttackWavFiles, turretMovedWavFiles, turretDie }; I'll come up with an example, sorry for my terrible post.

Comment: audioArrays is const char**[], but it decays in to const char** while being passed as an argument into playAudio().